# Safari showing JS error, but Chrome doesn't

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, referenceerror

I'm quite new to JS. I've been developing a couple of JS function. They work in Chrome. Yesterday I tried it in Safari and it's spitting out errors.

The function:

```
Request.SetForm = function (form, ruleset = [], messageset = null, focus = null, special = false, ignore = false) {

// Code here

}
```

I'm calling it like:

```
var $validator = Request.SetForm(arguments here);
```

Now Safari says:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Request

Well as I said, Chrome doesn't say anything and it works fine. What's wrong here?

Comment: Request is a part of `Fetch` - see http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch ... safari 10.1 is the minimum supported version - IOS Safari, no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to declare the Request before using.
use

```
var Request = {};
```

Then use

```
Request.method = function(){}
```

Because some older versions can't resolve a variable if not declared ( Normally the issue happen when we use in `use strict` mode.

Or else,
Request may be a keyword or built in method in the version of safari you are using.
So just change the name.

Comment: Thank you, that in fact was the reason.

Comment: I did. But I have no reputation so it doesn't get shown :(

Comment: (y) ok no problem bro. If you can mark it answer, try to do it. It may help someother person.